# Removing write protection from usb

Tags: usb-drive

The PCs in my college use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I tried plugging in my usb recently, but it wouldn't detect. So, I checked out the blacklist.conf file, and saw that usb_storage was blacklisted. I deleted that line, saved the file, and plugged in my pendrive. This time, it detected. But when I tried viewing the content, it said "You do not have the permissions to view the contents of blah blah blah...". This happened with any pendrive that I plugged in. One workaround I found, was typing in `gksu nautilus` in terminal. That allowed me to view the contents of the usb. But, I was only able to copy files from the usb on to the system. I wasn't able to copy files from the system on to the usb. What do I do?

Comment: I think there is a reason why usb_storage is blacklisted. If you want to use the  PCs in your college, it might be a better idea to boot from your own USB pendrive (if that is possible/allowed). Then you run your own system, and need not tamper with the installed system. See the following link and links from it, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Comment: I agree completely with @sudodus's opinion.

Comment: Actually, the reason why they blacklisted it is because no one in my college knows how to use Ubuntu or any Linux distro. They instead use Windows on VMWare. I on the other hand, was given permission by my teachers to do what I want with the PC. But they don't know how to remove the write protection.

Comment: And also, they wanted me to take some files from the computer onto a pendrive. Which is why I asked the question

Comment: Have you already tried what is described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/793378/678180)?

Comment: You can change ownership as described in the link by @MaximilianLaule. Or you can change the mount options if the partition on the USB drive is mounted read-only. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/886701/how-do-i-get-permission-to-edit-in-my-usb/886735#886735

Comment: The teacher may have given you permission to do as you ask, but I'm sure that the IT group wouldn't approve. What files are on this computer that you're trying to copy to a USB flash drive... games... school documents... etc? These machines are locked down for a reason.